# How to hide a sprite on trigger when the player enters the trigger zone?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I am making a roof for my 2D top down survival game, and I want to make it so that the roof disappears when the player enters the building, and re-appears when they leave.

Here is the code I've written so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Roof : MonoBehaviour { 
    public GameObject roofGameObject;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) { 
        roofGameObject.SetActive(false); 
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision) {
        roofGameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I got it to work so that, when I go in, the roof it disappears. But when I leave it stays disappeared. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is this script attached to the `roofGameObject` or one of its children, by any chance?

Comment: the roof game object

Comment: This script should not be part of the roof. Can you attach it and its trigger collider to the building instead? That way you won't get "trigger exit" messages when the roof is switched off.

Comment: Thanks so much its working now!

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that an inactive GameObject no longer checks for trigger events. So when the collider which triggers the reactivation of the roof is on the roof itself, then it won't be able to reactivate itself.

One solution is to separate the trigger area for activating and deactivating the roof and the roof itself into two separate GameObjects.

Another solution is to not deactivate the whole roof gameObject, but only its `Renderer` component. That way the roof will disappear visually, but anything else the roof does will still work:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) { 
    roofGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false; 
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision) {
    roofGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = true; 
}
```

By the way: Instead of making it disappear completely, you can also make it render slightly transparent. Assuming you are using a SpriteRenderer (as implied by 2d), you can do that by changing its [color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-color.html) property to something with a low alpha-value:

```
Color translucentWhite = new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.2f);

roofGameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = translucentWhite;
```

However, in a 3d game, you likely want to use a [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.SetPropertyBlock.html) instead of the color-property.

1. the performance is better (on the build-in render pipeline) because it doesn't create new materials at runtime each time you change the color .
2. When you have shaders which have more than one color property, then you can control which color(s) to change.

Comment: Interestingly, the performance advantage of material property block goes away on the new scriptable render pipelines, which just shove all their material properties into one big buffer and draw in a batches by shader anyway. Now I need to get in the habit of figuring out which rendering pipeline folks are using to know which performance advice is relevant to them. Transition periods are messy!

Comment: @DMGregory That's good to know.